# Bulk texture uploads

Tags: cuda, jpeg, textures

I have a specialised rendering app that needs to load up any number of jpegs from a pdf, and then write out the images into a rendered page inside a kernel. This is oversimplified, but the point is that I want to find a way to collectively send up 'n' images as textures, and then, within the kernel, to index into this collective of textures for tex2d() calls. Any ideas welcome for doing this gracefully.

As a side question, I haven't yet found a way to decode the jpeg images in the kernel, forcing me to decode on the CPU and then send up (slowly) a large bitmap. Can i improve this?

Answer (score 1):

First: if texture upload performance is not a bottleneck, consider not bulk uploading. Here are some suggestions, each with different trade-offs.

1. For varying-sized textures, consider creating a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas). This is a technique popular in game development that packs many textures into a single 2D image. This requires offsetting texture coordinates to the corner of the image in question, and it precludes the use of texture coordinate clamping and wrapping.  So you would need to store the offset of the corner of each sub-texture instead of its ID. There are various tools available for creating texture atlases.
2. For constant-sized textures, or for the case where you don't mind the waste of varying-sized textures, you could consider using a [layered texture](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#layered-textures). This is a texture with a number of independent layers that can be indexed at texture fetch time using a separate layer index.  Quote from the link above:

   > A one-dimensional or two-dimensional layered texture (also know as texture array in Direct3D and array texture in OpenGL) is a texture made up of a sequence of layers, all of which are regular textures of same dimensionality, size, and data type.
   >
   > A one-dimensional layered texture is addressed using an integer index and a floating-point texture coordinate; the index denotes a layer within the sequence and the coordinate addresses a texel within that layer. A two-dimensional layered texture is addressed using an integer index and two floating-point texture coordinates; the index denotes a layer within the sequence and the coordinates address a texel within that layer.
   >
   > A layered texture can only be a CUDA array by calling cudaMalloc3DArray() with the cudaArrayLayered flag (and a height of zero for one-dimensional layered texture).
   >
   > Layered textures are fetched using the device functions described in tex1Dlayered() and tex2Dlayered(). Texture filtering (see Texture Fetching) is done only within a layer, not across layers.
   >
   > Layered textures are only supported on devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher.
3. You could consider a hybrid approach: sort the textures into same-sized groups and use a layered texture for each group.  Or use a layered texture atlas, where the groups are packed such that each layer contains one or a few textures from each group to minimize waste.

Regarding your side question: a [google search for "cuda jpeg decode" turns up a lot of results](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=CUDA+jpeg+decode&oq=CUDA+jpeg+decode&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), including [at least one open source project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudajpegdecoder/).

Comment: Impressively quick! However I'm faced with different sized images, which i though precluded the use of layered textures?

Comment: then again, maybe I could set the layered texture to the biggest image and send up the various sizes as well....

Comment: I realized that limitation, but there is no other *built-in* way in CUDA to bulk upload 2D texture data except for layered or 3D textures.  I've edited my answer to add another option, the "texture atlas".